# Store method parameter names for some classes when building with Gradle/Java8

Tags: java, methods, parameters, gradle, java-8

Follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28073799/store-method-parameter-names-for-some-classes-when-compiling-in-java-8) question.

How do I store method parameter names for classes when building with Gradle (build.gradle file)?

According to Java [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodparameterreflection.html):

> To store formal parameter names in a particular .class file,  and thus
>   enable the Reflection API to retrieve formal parameter names,  compile
>   the source file with the -parameters option to the javac compiler.

So How do I pass the "-parameters" to the *javac* compiler using Gradle?

I tried the suggested solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554829/passing-arguments-to-compiler-and-javadoc-in-gradle), by adding the below into my *build.gradle* file **with no luck**.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << '-parameters'
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.executable = 'javac'
}
```

I'm using eclipse and if I enable this (in Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler), it works fine.

```
Store information about method parameters (usable via reflection)
```

But I would rather have this setting set by my build system, so i don't depend on eclipse and so others can use my buildt .jar files.

I use:

- Eclipse 4.4.2
- Gradle IDE 3.6.4 (eclipse plugin)

Answer (score 2):

To get gradle itself to compile with `-parameters` add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
compileJava.options.compilerArgs.add '-parameters'
compileTestJava.options.compilerArgs.add '-parameters'
```

In order to use Gradle to generate Eclipse project files where `-parameters` is set for javac: Use a tip from [this gradle forum post](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-write-properties-to-3rd-party-eclipse-settings-files/6499/3) and add the following to your `build.gradle`:

```
eclipseProject {
  doLast {
    // https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-write-properties-to-3rd-party-eclipse-settings-files/6499/2

    def props = new Properties()
    file(".settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs").withInputStream {
      stream -> props.load(stream)
    }
    props.setProperty("org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.methodParameters", "generate")
    file(".settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs").withOutputStream {
      stream -> props.store(stream, null)
    }
}
```

}

(Apparently a) the Gradle Eclipse plugin doesn't know how to translate the compiler option `-parameters` to the `.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs` setting `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.methodParameters=generate` and b) there's no standard Gradle task that manipulates any of the property files in `.settings`, so you've got to roll your own.)

This is for Gradle 2.8.

Answer (score 1):

```
sourceCompatibility=1.8
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.compilerArgs = ['-parameters']
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research for the same problem, one solution is to make something like this: https://github.com/codeborne/mobileid/blob/master/build.gradle

Add this to your build.gradle:

```
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options.collect {options ->
    options.compilerArgs.add '-parameters'
}
```

It works for me with gradle 2.4